# Ruby on Rails (rake db:seed) - Undefined Attribute Error ___

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I'm getting this error:

> "ActiveRecord: UndefinedAttributeError: Unknown Attribute: name"

whenever I try to rake seed.db. I honestly have no idea what's wrong because I defined name in my migration files already.

Here's my code.

Seeds.rb -

```
 P1 = Post.create(name: "Arsenal")
 P2 = Post.create(name: "Chelsea")
```

Migration -

```
   class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :posts do |t|
          t.string :name
        end
      end
    end
```

Let me know if you need anymore files.

Comment: did u run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It works when try to rake db:migrate. I tried multiple times.

Comment: Try creating in the console to troubleshoot.  You can also enter "Post" in the console to ensure there is a name attribute for the model.

Comment: Sorry, fairly new to this. Do you mean just enter Post in terminal? When I do that it just says 'post is not recognized as an internal or external command... '

Comment: No worries.  Run the rails console from your terminal (`rails c`).  You should see a prompt like `>>`.  If you've never done this, start making it a habit (I always have a terminal handy running the console).  It is a great place to try things (even small code fragments).  Anything you can do in your seed file, you should be able to do in the interactive console.  You can also query the console with a model name like `Post` and you will see what your dev environment thinks `Post` looks like.

Comment: I didn't see the ">>" prompt, I'm doing this in the command prompt with ruby and rails, if that's correct.

However, when I entered "Post" it told me
 (call 'Post.connection' to establish a connection) irb(main):005:0>

Comment: Are you running in Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows, lol. I just realized you were talking about Linux.

Comment: Yes and sadly this is where we part ways but you should be able to research "run rails console in windows" or something like that.

Comment: Have you created migration file by hand or using "rails g migration..." If not try `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create` then `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed`